# How to patch Vcl.Forms.pas?

Tags: delphi, styles, patch

Sydney had this nasty bug ([Close second form with cafree close all application in vcl styles](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-33140)) that Emba fixed it in Alexandria:

[image]

What is the best way to add this fix to Sydney?
It would be nice to be able to call it with a single line from every project.

Comment: You would have to either 1) make a copy of `Vcl.Forms.pas` and patch it, then add that file to every project (does not work if Runtime Packages are enabled), or 2) recompile the whole VCL library.

Comment: Hi Remy - Yes, the bug being in the Forms.pas is unfortunate. Did you ever succeed to compile the whole VCL? I have tried (many years ago, it is true) and it was not possible. I will try tonight.

Comment: "add that file to every project" - Sound good. I just have to remember to ALWAYS have that unit the last one in the "uses" clause.... I could even add a verification in my code to make sure that is always the case...